# Number of non-singular matrices with entries in $\{1, -1\}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

What is the number of non-singular $n \times n$ matrices  with entries in $\{1, -1\}$? Here I assume that two such matrices are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by permutations of rows and columns, or change of signs of rows and columns. An estimate would help.

How about non-singular matrices with entries in $\{1, 0, -1\}$?

Comment: What do you get for $n=1, n=2, n=3$?

Comment: this can be equivalently phrased as probability a random $\pm 1$ $n\times n$ matrix is non-singular, which is very hard (I think)

Comment: @Gerald only one.

Comment: With respect to @mathworker21's comment, [this recent pre-print](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09016.pdf) tightens some old bounds, but the [old bounds](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1995-08-01/S0894-0347-1995-1260107-2/) are enough to say that asymptotically almost all such matrices are non-singular.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much. Please post your comment as an answer, I will upvote it.